# Langtons Ant in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm a very new Programmer and am learning Java atm. I am writing a Langton's Ant, however I can't seem to get my ant to do what it's supposed to. The ant only seems to run up and down the grid and stays within column 10 and 11.
Here is the code:

```
package ameise;

public class Ant {
    // Variables
    // Position of the ant
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    // Which way is the ant facing
    String direction;
    Grid g;
    boolean isFinished;

    public Ant(int xPos, int yPos, String direction, Grid g) {
        // Constructor
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.g = g;
    }

    // Getter X Y Coordinates
    public int getXPos() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public int getYPos() {
        return yPos;
    }

    // Setter X Y Coordinates
    protected void setXPos(int xPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
    }

    protected void setYPos(int yPos) {
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

    public String getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    protected void setDirection(String direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (xPos >= 0 && yPos >= 0 && xPos < g.getWidth() && yPos < g.getHeight()) {
            System.out.println(xPos + "," + yPos + "," + "Facing " + direction + " Color " + g.isWhite(xPos, yPos));
            if (xPos == 0) {
                isFinished = true;
            } else if (xPos == g.getWidth()) {
                isFinished = true;
            } else if (yPos == 0) {
                isFinished = true;
            } else if (yPos == g.getHeight()) {
                isFinished = true;
            }

            // Determine Directions ...

            if (direction.equals("NORTH")) {
                if (g.isWhite(xPos, yPos)) {
                    g.setBlack(xPos, yPos);
                    setDirection("WEST");
                } else {
                    g.setWhite(xPos, yPos);
                    setDirection("EAST");
                }
                yPos++;
            } else if (direction.equals("WEST")) {
                if (g.isWhite(xPos, yPos)) {
                    g.setBlack(xPos, yPos);
                    setDirection("SOUTH");
                } else {
                    g.setWhite(xPos, yPos);
                    setDirection("NORTH");
                }
                xPos--;
            } else if (direction.equals("SOUTH")) {
                if (g.isWhite(xPos, yPos)) {
                    g.setBlack(xPos, yPos);
                    setDirection("EAST");
                } else {
                    g.setWhite(xPos, yPos);
                    setDirection("WEST");
                }
                yPos--;
            }

            else if (direction.equals("EAST")) {
                if (g.isWhite(xPos, yPos)) {
                    g.setBlack(xPos, yPos);
                    setDirection("NORTH");
                } else {
                    g.setWhite(xPos, yPos);
                    setDirection("SOUTH");
                }
                xPos++;
            }
        }
    }
}
*** CLASS GRID ***  
package ameise;

public class Grid {
    // Define the variables
    boolean[][] grid;
    int height;
    int width;

    // constructor with user parameters
    public Grid(int height, int width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        grid = new boolean[height][width];
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
                grid[h][w] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Methods
    // Getter and Setter for grid
    public boolean[][] getGrid() {
        return grid;
    }

    public void setGrid(boolean[][] grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public boolean isWhite(int h, int w) {
        return grid[h][w];
    }

    protected void setWhite(int h, int w) {
        if (h < height && w < width)
            grid[h][w] = true;
    }

    protected void setBlack(int h, int w) {
        if (h < height && w < width)
            grid[h][w] = false;
    }

    public void printGrid() {
        for (int h = 0; h < 19; h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < 19; w++) {
                if (isWhite(h, w)) {
                    System.out.printf("S", grid[h][w]);
                } else
                    System.out.printf("X", grid[h][w]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
*** MAIN CLASS***
public class Main {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grid grid = new Grid(20, 20);
        Ant ant = new Ant(10, 10, "NORTH", grid);
        ant.run();
        grid.printGrid();
    }
}
```

Somehow the ant only seems to be running. The output looks like

```
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSXXSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSXXSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSXXSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSXXSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSXXSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSXXSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSXXSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSXXSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSXXSSSSSSS
    SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
```

Comment: are you talking about the `ant` (animal) or `ant` (apache ant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Langton's Ant moves into a cell and based on it's color decides which way it will turn to leave the current cell. Your code decides which way to turn but leaves in the direction it was already facing:

```
if (direction.equals("NORTH")) {
   // This section decides which way ant will go based on the current cell
   if (g.isWhite(xPos, yPos)) {
      g.setBlack(xPos, yPos);
      setDirection("WEST");
   } else {
      g.setWhite(xPos, yPos);
      setDirection("EAST");
   }
   // This section move north, not in the direction the ant turns.
   yPos++;
} //...
```

I think the best way to fix it is replace each case with something like:

```
if (direction.equals("NORTH")) {
   if (g.isWhite(xPos, yPos)) {
      g.setBlack(xPos, yPos);
      setDirection("WEST");
      xPos--; //move West
   } else {
      g.setWhite(xPos, yPos);
      setDirection("EAST");
      xPos++; //move East
   }
} //...
```